# method defined but gives the error: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

There is foreign_key for the relation on database, and method is defined, but I have a grievous problem, in Laravel 6.

There was no problem, but after upgrade from 5.4 to 6 the problem arised.

---

User Model:

```
public function partner() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Partner','id', 'partner_id');
}
```

---

In Controller:
This code return error:

```
    $partner = User::find(4)->partner->title;
    return var_dump($partner);
```

**Trying to get property 'title' of non-object**

---

And this return NULL

```
    $partner = User::find(4)->partner->title;
    return var_dump($partner);
```

(4 id has a existing user, partner_id is assigned to it, and partners table is available)

Comment: Whats is the differences between 2 query? Edit please, your both codes are same

Answer (score 0):

You've placed wrong param.

```
public function partner() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Partner','partner_id','id');
}

return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

The first key would be `'foreign_key'` and next `'local_key'`

check document [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this. In your `partners` table use foreign key `user_id` and model should be like below

```
public function partner() {

    return $this->hasOne('App\Partner','user_id', 'id');
}
```